# How can I find the default Android resource (e.g. drawable etc) for a View

Tags: android, user-interface, themes

I've been styling and theming various components like ListView today and I was wondering what is the easiest way to find out what the default resource, color, drawable etc is for a given xml attribute. For example View has a [android:scrollbarTrackVertical](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3ascrollbarTrackVertical) attibute for which the docs says:

> This corresponds to the global attribute resource symbol [scrollbarTrackVertical](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#scrollbarTrackVertical).

Well, that's all fine and dandy but when I navigate to the docs for R.attr but that won't give me the name of the actual reference in the platform source code, which might be a good starting point for styling stuff in the first place.

Am I missing something in the docs or is there a trick to figure out the "default" values for a given platform release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get most of default values from [style.xml](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/styles.xml) file. Also, [themes.xml](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/themes.xml) file contains some defaults, but not widgets' defaults. But usually it's rather useful too.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the missing link: dig up the style.xml or themes.xml from the platform sdk dir (like @dmon mentioned), then check those xmls for references to the real resources. The platform resource ref is @null btw for the example I gave :)

Comment: I've never used files from this folder, because I use downloaded Android sources. But anyway, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 6):

All of the layout XMLs and drawable resources are in your SDK folder already: `androidsdk\platforms\android-N\data\res`